# html image not loading when uploaded to webhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

So I have this 2 images that have the same syntax as the others but is not loading. You could check it out here at http://lsehau.comuf.com/gallery.html . Can't really figure out how to fix these things. Prob is, when it's on my webhost(000webhost) it only shows the problem there, but when I just open it with my chrome, it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution
try changing `src="class.jpg"`
to src="class.JPG" this is it i'm pretty sure i did it and it's working
same thing to `src="end.JPG"` and `src="class2.JPG"`
If you don't see the result at that moment, that doesn't mean it's not working, it needs sometime. Hope i helped!

Comment: Yes i've tried it out and its working! :) I've only got the other 2 left not loading, already did the uppercase stuff.

Comment: Oh wait, forgot to re-edit the other ones. It works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is what I answered first

Comment: You would be better to rename the file to a lower case extension and keep all the images consistently named.

Answer (score 1):

i think you didn't load correctly the file class.jpg, because when i go to your images file in : inspect element->sources->images, i don't find class.jpg. Please check that!

Answer (score 0):

Hello there qApps thanks for replying to my questions, prob is, I do have it properly named here: [[prob here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykpbH.png)

its also the same with the other not loading pictures :(

Here's a screenshot on how it works when I just open it here locally in my pc: [local view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVqQE.png)

Comment: Does the web page sit in the *finals* directory on the server as well as locally?

Comment: Yes it does, I have seperated my image files to an "images folder" and I am referring to them with my html as images/namehere.format .

Comment: you must have a mistake or in extensions or in uppercase or maybe the file's name. you may want to remove all source attributes and do them again and see!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an uppercase file extension in your uploaded filename.

```
http://lsehau.comuf.com/images/class.JPG
```

loads ok, but in your code you refer to `.jpg`

```
http://lsehau.comuf.com/images/class.jpg
```

returns not found.

You should rename your image file.

Comment: This has caught me out before

Comment: Hello RouthMedia! Hmmm, I've only been referring to lower case .jpg on every image files I have, should I change them all to uppercase then?

Comment: Yeap, double checked it just now. I have used only lowercase jpg with all my html files and img hrefs.

Comment: always try and keep things consistent. I always use lowercase for code and file extensions.

Comment: You need to rename your uploaded file and give it a lowercase extension

Comment: We'll be trying this in a minute or so, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:
You have different files extensions png and jpg, be sure that they all fit with your code source, and also check for uppercase and lower case

Comment: What do you mean that I make sure that they all fit with my source code? Do you mean I should achieve unit and just use one single image file extension? Thanks!

Comment: i mean for example you may refer in your code to : src="images/image.png" but the file is image.jpg you should check for that

Comment: Welp, just double checked it out now. It's good. both are jpg files and im both referencing them as jpg files. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem! And well, really to tell you this is very confusing and crazy, try maybe to switch to another web hosting service

Comment: Well if we just have the money we would. But, we've only uploaded our site within a free web host since we'll only be using it as our final output in our web programming 1 class. If you could suggest any better free web hosting service out there it would be a great help! Anw again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jjjmnz please can you rate my answer as best answer if you think it is?

Comment: There! I also tried upvoting but it seems like I am not allowed to do so since I'm new to the site.

Comment: ok, i'm actually banned from asking, the policy of the website is very strict, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone who has helped! And yeap, the problem was with the file extension (being case sensitive, didn't know that my friend saved some of these images manually as ".JPG" instead of ".jpg".) Thanks a lot! Leaving this out here in case someone would have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using github hosting service. It gives you .github.io domain. And it's free! Tell me if you think it's good.